# How to force traffic out to router when it is bound for another network interface inside the computer

Tags: networking, iptables

I have a computer with two network interfaces, say eth0 and eth1 with IPes 192.168.1.10 and 192.168.1.11 respectively. Both these interfaces are connected to a router directly.

When I send traffic to 192.168.1.11 from 192.168.1.10 (or let Linux 'choose' interface itself), due to default entries in linux local routing table, traffic would never leave for the network and would get routed internally. How can I delete these entries from local routing table and add in some other routing table such that traffic for 192.168.1.11 is forced out to the router.

There must be some "ip" or "iptables" way which I couldn't' figure out.

Comment: Do you have an actual reason for wanting to do this?

Comment: you might get what you want by removing the route to 192.168.1.11 from the `local` table (`ip route del 192.168.1.11/32 table local`) and explicitly adding it with the router as the gateway to the default routing table. But I suspect this would break more than it could ever fix.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ip r del ...` and `ip r add ...`?

Anyway please post `ip r` output to be sure you properly explain the case.

Comment: More of a comment than a answer